# Unit of work in CQRS-command

Tags: unit-of-work, cqrs

How does everyone solve the "unit of work" in CQRS?
I want a command that updates "Title" and "Description", but not "Links"..

someclass
{
  string Title;
  string Description;
  string[] Links;
}

Comment: I just started thinking about ViewModels, which we use to fit a specific View. Has anyone thought about "CommandModels" which would fit that specific command? Is that what you mean by "Transport message"?

Comment: what do you mean "CommandModels"?

Comment: "CommandModels" is a new word that I just invented .. I guess you know what a ViewModel is and what it is used for - it feels like we have a similar problem when we want to get data from the view and store it. How about creating a command-model which fit the unit-of-work? But it might be me that is missing out on something..

Comment: You don't need CommandModels because if you do, you will have consistency problems. What will be single source of truth - it seems it is not your domain model as should be? How to get data from "CommandModel" to your domain model?

Comment: Interesting comments, thanks for the help! I believe I understand your arguments, right now it feels like I need some good articles on the subject and how to apply it in practice. I guess I have some reading to do..

Comment: I recommend to watch video from Greg Young's class http://cqrsinfo.com/video/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create an UpdateTitleAndDescriptionCommand. Entire-entity CRUD is overrated and most often causes race conditions in collaborative environments.